# Cascading entity save with composite key throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have this relationship structure in database, that I cannot change:

```
------------------------
| Person               | 
------------------------
 id : pk              
------------------------

------------------------
| PersonAddress        | 
------------------------
 person_id: pk, fk    
 address_id: pk, fk
 address_type 
------------------------

------------------------
| Address              | 
------------------------
 id: pk    
------------------------
```

I am trying to configure these relations with JPA and Hibernate annotations.
One of the ways I've tried to do was this one:

```
@Entity
class Person {

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
  private List<PersonAddress> addresses;
}

@Entity
class PersonAddress {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
  private AddressType type;

  @EmbeddedId
  private PersonAddressId id;
}


@Embeddable
class PersonAddressId implements Serializable {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
  private Person person;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @MapsId("id")
  @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", nullable = false)
  private Address address;

}

@Entity
public class Address {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "address_id")
  private Long id;
}
```

When i do `repository.save(person)`. I expect that changes would cascade down to the address.

The problem is that, when I try to save, I get NullPointerException. While debugging I found out, that Hibernate tries to save PersonAddress object, and it needs hash code of one of the primary keys it uses.

Since Address is not yet save, it has id == null.  Basically the flow of save is currently:

```
Person -> PersonAddress -> Address
```

But it should be:

```
Person -> Address -> PersonAddress
```

(because it needs to get generated ids for person and adddress).

Is there a way to configure Hibernate to behave in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the problem. When creating `@Embeddable` class for primary key usage, you need to provide simple objects for id columns. I.e. it should not contain objects mapped by foreign key:

```
@Embeddable
class PersonAddressId implements Serializable {

@Column(nullable = false)
private Long relatedPartyId;

@Column(nul
private Long addressId;

}
```

To support composite primary key, as well as foreign keys, you need to add `@MapsId` annotation:

```
@Entity
public class Person Address {

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("personId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private RelatedParty relatedParty;

  @EmbeddedId
  @JsonIgnore
  private RelatedPartyAddressId id;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("addressId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", nullable = false)
  private Address address;

}
```

Comment: I've run into the same problem, however, my ID was mapped through IdClass. With IdClass however, the @MapsId didn't work. In any case, after switching to EmbeddedId and using the simple types it works. But I still don't understand if this behavior is a bug or a feature. During my debuging, I was expecting Hibernate to go from top to down in the One-To-Many relations, but it first tried to create the child entity and get the ID parameter from the parent, which was not persisted at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your hashCode method is wrong implemented. You must always check for null because this method can be called in various situations.

Read more about that topic: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/

Comment: But Hibernate does not use entities hash code, in `org.hibernate.type.EntityType` method `getHashCode` it extracts id field (which is null, because Address is not persisted yet) and runs hashCode on it. Even though all entities have hashCode method defined.

Comment: HashCode can be called when putting the object into a HashMap, HashTable, HashSet or any other collection that uses a hash code to organize the structure.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, although it does not solve the problem I am facing with null pointer exception.

Comment: Where do you get the NPE? Still in the hashCode method? If yes make it NPE save.

Comment: Hibernate takes object of type `Address`, using reflection detects what is the `@Id` field of this object (it does not use `Address::hashCode`) and then calls hash code on this field, (`address.id.hashCode()`), and since id is null it fails. I cannot control this behaviour in any way by overriding `hashCode`. It has to do something with JPA annotations.

Comment: can you show the code how you create the objects and persist them?

Comment: persisting is done via calling Spring Data repository
`personRepository.save(person)`
And creating objects is just creating new object via constructor and assigning it to other object, if needed, 
for example `var person = new Person(); person.setAddreses(Array.asList(personAddress)`